# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: t._freezeSettings is not a function. (In 't._freezeSettings()', 't._freezeSettings' is undefined)]

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i am using react native with firestore. As a result of these codes, I get the error in the title:

```
const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
const dailyRef = firebase.firestore().collection('daily');

 setDoc(doc(dailyRef,email ), {
    name:"name",
    email:email });

const q = query(dailyRef, where("email", "==", email));
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Found out that, Instead of using the collection from `firebase.firestore()` directly, you will have to import the `collection` function from the firestore library itself and then pass your db like so:

```
import { collection } from "firebase/firestore"; // <---Use collection from this package
const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
const db = firebase.firestore();
const dailyRef = collection(db, 'daily');

 setDoc(doc(dailyRef,email ), {
    name:"name",
    email:email });

const q = query(dailyRef, where("email", "==", email));
```